# Shell for loop, stopping at declaration

Tags: linux, shell, for-loop

I'm trying to write a for loop that goes from 1 to 10, then calculates ( 1 through 10 mod 5) + 2. After that I want to display it like this (1 to 10 mod 5) + 2 = answer. However i'm getting an error at the beginning of the loop which is a syntax error.

```
for (( i = 0; i <= 10; i++)); do
    calculate=(i % 5) + 2
    echo ("("i "% 5) + 2" calculate)
done
```

Comment: Linux is not a programming language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these changes:

```
calculate=$(( i % 5 + 2 ))         
  # $(( ... )) is the shell's way to do arithmetic
echo "($i % 5) + 2 = " $calculate  
  # $x is a way to refer to the value of variable x 
  # (also inside a double-quoted string)
```

The for loop header is actually OK.

Comment: This is shell, not Perl or PHP, you don't need `;` at theend of each line.

Comment: @Barmar you're right, I copy/pasted from a one-liner version which had those semicolons.